# Problema en ciclo en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este planteamiento:

> Leer 10 números enteros, almacenarlos en una lista y determinar
>   cuántos números de los almacenados en dicha lista terminan en 15

Tengo este código, pero no se en donde es que me estoy equivocando; por mas que miro no se donde esta el error.

Siempre me dice que no hay números terminados en 15:

Este es mi código:

```
try:

    lista=[]
    lista2=[]
    acumulador=0
    aumento=0

    for i in range(10):
        numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
        lista.append(numero)

    for l in range(len(lista)):
        numeros=lista[l]
        aumento=0
        while numeros>0:
            digito=numeros%10
            if digito==5:
                digito=numeros//10
                if digito==1:
                    aumento+=1

            numeros=numeros//10         

    if aumento>0:
        print("Hay %d"% + " numeros que terminan en 15")

    else:
        print("No hay numeros que terminen en 15")  

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu lógica es incorrecta.

Toma por ejemplo el número 215, que termina en 15 y examinemos paso a paso qué ocurre en tu bucle `while`.

La variable `numeros` (mal nombre ¿por qué en plural si sólo tiene un número?) comenzaría valiendo `215`. Al hacer `digito=numeros%10` el resultado es `5`, por lo que entra el el `if`. De momento bien.

Pero dentro del `if` haces `digito=numeros//10`, que es la división entera entre 10 y por tanto produce `21`. En este caso `digito==1` no se cumple y no se incrementa la variable `aumento` (mal nombre ¿por qué no. llamarla `contador`, ya que es eso lo que hace?). En realidad no queríamos mirar que fuera `1`, sino que *terminara* en 1.

Entonces haces `numeros = numeros//10`, con lo que `numeros` pasa a valer `21` y repites el bucle. En esta segunda iteración ya no se cumple que `numeros%10` sea 5 (no tiene sentido de hecho mirar eso, habría que mirar en este caso si es `1` para detectar si termina en 15), por lo que no se entra en el `if`. Finalmente `numeros = numeros//10` dejaría la variable con el valor `2` y en la última iteración tampoco se incrementa `aumento`.

Puedes probar a imaginar la ejecución paso a paso con otros datos de entrada, pero está claro que sólo funciona correctamente si el dato de entrada es `15`, y no si *termina* en 15.

Además, haces `aumento=0` para cada iteración del bucle `for`, por lo que incluso si metieras un dato `15` que se detectara correctamente y aumentara `aumento`, en la siguiente iteración (siguiente dato) lo pondrías de nuevo a 0. Tu programa sólo da el resultado correcto si en toda la lista ningún número termina en 15, o si sólo  el último es 15.

### Correcciones

Una forma mucho más sencilla de detectar si un número termina en `15` sería calcular el resto de dividir por 100. Si ese resto es 15, es que termina en 15. Es decir, si `numeros%100 == 15`.

Aparte de eso, otras correcciones menores en tu código:

- Los nombres de variables. Aunque pueda parecer un detalle, son importantes. Cuando escribes código no lo haces sólo para indicarle al computador qué hacer (para eso cualquier nombre de variable es válido), sino también para comunicar a otras personas (o a ti mismo cuando lo leas dentro de un tiempo) cómo funciona el programa o en qué estabas pensando cuando lo escribiste. Programar es una forma de comunicarse con otros programadores.

  En este sentido yo cambiaría de nombre `aumento` y lo llamaría `contador`, y cambiaría `numeros` y lo llamaría `numero`. También es costumbre llamar `i` a las variables que actúan como índice de bucle (en vez de la `l` que has usado).

  La variable `lista2` no se usa. Se puede quitar. De cualquier forma tampoco era un buen nombre ¿qué pensabas meter en ella? ¿Los números que cumplieran terminar en 15? Entonces podrías llamarla `elegidos`, o `terminados_en_15`. La variable `acumulador` también sobra.
- La forma de recorrer una lista en Python suele ser  `for numero in lista:`, lo que hace que la variable `numero` vaya tomando los valores de los elementos de la lista. La forma en que tú lo has hecho: `for i in range(len(lista)): numero = lista[i]` es la forma típica de hacerlo en otros lenguajes (ej: C) que no tienen un bucle `for` tan potente como Python.
- El `print()` que imprimiría cuántos números hay está mal, le falta la variable a imprimir.
- El bloque `try/catch` es demasiado grande. Estás intentando capturar el caso en que el usuario introduzca algo que no se pueda convertir en número. Eso sólo puede ocurrir durante la lectura de datos, por lo que yo reduciría el bloque `try:` exclusivamente a esa lectura, dejando fuera la parte del procesamiento de la lista.

Es decir, lo dejaría así:

```
lista=[]

try:
    for i in range(10):
        numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
        lista.append(numero)
except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
    quit()

contador = 0
for numero in lista:
    if numero % 100 == 15:
        contador += 1

if contador>0:
    print("Hay %d numeros que terminan en 15" % contador)
else:
    print("No hay numeros que terminen en 15")
```

Comment: muchas gracias por haberme explicado los errores y las correcciones abulafia tomare en cuenta los consejos que me acabas de dar

Comment: @Andress115, si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, por favor **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si el objetivo es capturar los números que acaben en "15", creo que lo más sencillo sería, en vez de hacerlo mediante tipos numéricos, hacerlo mediante cadenas. Por ejemplo:

```
lista1 = [1, 23, 45, 215, 33, 441, 115, 15, 345]
resultado = [numero for numero in lista1 if str(numero).endswith("15")]

print("Hay %d números acabados en 15" % len(resultado))
print(resultado)
```

Que daría como salida:

```
Hay 3 números acabados en 15
[215, 115, 15]
```